# Unable to run Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-center, crash

When I click on "Ubuntu Software" in order to install new packages
it first opens, but crashes after a seconds.

Any idea how i can overcome this issue?

Comment: Fully update your system and try again. Two ways: 1) Running Updates or 2) In terminal: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge software-center` should reinstall the software center and might fix it